# Swift: How to play short sounds longer

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudioplayer

I'm working on a SpriteKit project using Swift and I wanted to play my 1 sec long sound longer. For instance, the sound file is "beep" - I want it to be extended to something like "beeeep" or "beeeeeeeeep". I'm tried several options to play a sound file, but I can't find a way to extend it.

Currently, I'm using SKAction to play sound:

```
var beep = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("beep.caf", waitForCompletion: false)
runAction(beep)
```

Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: maybe set the `waitForCompletion` to true and put `runAction(beep)` in loop.

Comment: Would it make sense if you slowed down the sound to make it play longer?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I actually tried that approach already but I didn't get the correct result. The output is something like "beepbeepbeep".

Comment: @neo No. slowing down the sound will change the pitch. so instead of tiny "beep" you will hear "BBEEEEEEEEP".

Comment: i think if you cut the very first part of sound. you wont get "beepbeepbeep"... This is how actually synthesizers, sequencers works to create one long sound effect from 1 sec of sound effect.They make a loop from section of sound material Not the whole sound. you may need program to do it. but if it does not support `caf` you can convert it to `wav` which is very popular format and most tools support wav.

Comment: Playing the sound continuously will not work because there's a pause included in the sound file and there's no way to alter a sound file from within Xcode. You can either cut the pause from the sound file with some other software or find a new sound fie.

Answer (score 0):

`AVAudioPlayer` has a `rate` property which lets you play at half to double speed. If half works, you can use that.

If that does not work, you can use `AVComposition` to create a composite track from your sound file. You can select portions of the sound file and stitch them together anyway you like.